# Connecting Instagram with facebook gives error_type OauthException

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

I tried to connect my instagram profile via my facebook page in the settings area. When I try to log in to my account in the popup window this is what it says:

{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Session invalid"}

Also when I try to connect my facebook in the Instagram app on my phone it won't connect just for 1 - 5 seconds.

Comment: please add in detail what you have tried and what exactly led to that error, this is a platform for developers, so write error descriptions for developers ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Luschn! I tried to connect my instagram profile via my facebook page in the settings area. When I try to log in to my account in the popup window this is what it says. Also when I try to connect my facebook in the Instagram app on my phone it won't connect.

I think thats about all the info I can give you..

Comment: edit your question. never post relevant information in comments. and please add screenshots of your problem. btw, i hope your instagram account is a business account?

Comment: It is a business account yes! I will update the post.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I solved it by disabling my AdBlock and Pop Up blocker in both

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by going to my instagram app

Edite profile > Public business Information > Page

and now you can Disconnect, connect, change or create a page.